# ":checked" selector doesn't change back to original selector state

Tags: css, svg

I have a logo (svg) in which the :checked selector has to return to it's standard state of #close * and overwrite the transition and rotate the bars back to their original state. With :hover this is no problem at all. If possible please try to stick to CSS. If that's not possible, just tell me that i have to write something in JS.
Here is my code:

```css
#logo *{
opacity: 0%;
transform-box: fill-box;
transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
#logo #background, #logo #background *{
opacity: 100%;
}
#logo_check{
display: none;
}
#close, #close *{
transition: transform 0.15s linear 0s, opacity 0.01s linear 0.15s;
}
#logo_check:checked + label #close, label #close *{
opacity: 100%;
transition: opacity 0.01s linear 0.15s, transform 0.15s linear 0.15s;
}
#logo_check:checked + label #bar_rot_left{
transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
#logo_check:checked + label #bar_rot_right{
transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="logo_check">
<label for="logo_check">
<svg id="logo" viewBox="0 0 202 246" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g id="background">
     <path id="mappin" d="M105.428 241.896C103.987 243.351 102.693 244.973 100.741 244.964C98.8209 244.985 97.5561 243.503 95.9431 241.952L28.3145 170.526C12.6484 154.455 0.247026 129.06 0.148815 99.7311C5.93731 -29.9072 191.844 -36.154 201.332 99.7522C200.439 134.218 187.642 154.753 168.893 175.175L105.428 241.896V241.896Z" fill="#FE5900"/>
 </g>
 <g id="close">
  <path id="bar_rot_left" d="M47.162 87.0183C41.5164 87.0827 41.6953 99.0792 47.2062 98.9996L153.789 98.9447C159.774 98.8405 159.03 86.9603 153.759 87.0001L47.162 87.0182L47.162 87.0183Z" fill="#FEFEFE" stroke="white" stroke-width="0.297609"/>
  <path id="bar_rot_right" d="M47.162 87.0183C41.5164 87.0827 41.6953 99.0792 47.2062 98.9996L153.789 98.9447C159.774 98.8405 159.03 86.9603 153.759 87.0001L47.162 87.0182L47.162 87.0183Z" fill="#FEFEFE" stroke="white" stroke-width="0.297609"/>
 </g>
 </svg>
</label>
```

**Edit:**
The Animation did not work correctly, because of some code i left away. Should work now. But this was never the point in my question. The transition dosn't return to its original state after the state of the selector changed.

Comment: Add `transform-box: fill-box;transform-origin:50%;` to `#close, #close *`

Comment: You need to add `translateX()` & `translateY()` property also for set position for **cross sign**.

Comment: `enxaneta` You provided `transform-box: fill-box;transform-origin:50%` on `#close` working fine and also we can set close sign by `translateX` & `translateY` property.

Answer (score 2):

Add `transform-origin:center` & `transform-box: fill-box` property on `#close, #close *`  section then `cross` sign will draw on *middle center* of *svg* shape and also I have added **tilled** Operator on **:checked** property.
Check below snippet.

```css
svg{
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
#close, #close *{
  transition: transform 0.15s linear 0s, opacity 0.01s linear 0.15s;
  transform-box: fill-box;
  transform-origin:50%;
}
#logo_check:checked ~ #close{
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.01s linear 0.15s, transform 0.15s linear 0.15s;
}
#logo_check:checked ~ svg #bar_rot_left{
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
#logo_check:checked ~ svg #bar_rot_right{
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="logo_check">
  <svg id="logo" viewBox="0 0 202 246" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g id="background">
      <path id="mappin" d="M105.428 241.896C103.987 243.351 102.693 244.973 100.741 244.964C98.8209 244.985 97.5561 243.503 95.9431 241.952L28.3145 170.526C12.6484 154.455 0.247026 129.06 0.148815 99.7311C5.93731 -29.9072 191.844 -36.154 201.332 99.7522C200.439 134.218 187.642 154.753 168.893 175.175L105.428 241.896V241.896Z" fill="#FE5900"/>
    </g>
    <g id="close">
      <path id="bar_rot_left" d="M47.162 87.0183C41.5164 87.0827 41.6953 99.0792 47.2062 98.9996L153.789 98.9447C159.774 98.8405 159.03 86.9603 153.759 87.0001L47.162 87.0182L47.162 87.0183Z" fill="#FEFEFE" stroke="white" stroke-width="0.297609"/>
      <path id="bar_rot_right" d="M47.162 87.0183C41.5164 87.0827 41.6953 99.0792 47.2062 98.9996L153.789 98.9447C159.774 98.8405 159.03 86.9603 153.759 87.0001L47.162 87.0182L47.162 87.0183Z" fill="#FEFEFE" stroke="white" stroke-width="0.297609"/>
    </g>
  </svg>
</label>
```

Comment: You probably did not understand my question correctly. The goal is to have two transitions one with an offset of 0.15s for when the input get checked (" transform 0.15s linear 0.15s") and one for the standard/ unchecked state with 0s offset ("transform 0.15s linear 0s"). Your answer just works with "transform 0.15s linear 0s" but does't start with " transform 0.15s linear 0.15s" and has therefore the same problem as my question.